# YouTube Images not available in API, but can be accessed directly?

Tags: api, video, youtube

We are looking to show a carousel of YouTube Images for say the latest 5 videos. When we access via the API we can see the following images are accessible for ALL videos:

default, 120 x 90 - 
medium, 320 x 180 - 
high, 480 x 360

However we would like to access the 'maxres' versions, which, for most of the videos are infact available, via a direct link

e.g. https://i.ytimg.com/vi/GjNUYnvXU0Q/maxresdefault.jpg

Why do these maxresdefault images not appear via the API? The reason we require them via the API is so we can do a detect to see if they are available or not, and if not, skip showing that particular video.

We are accessing the list of videos by simply using:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=XXXXXX&order=date&type=video&maxResults=5